# Communication between controllers through Custom delegates

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I have obtained response from server in a `Dictionary`. Now, I have a button on `ViewControllerA`. On the click of that button, I want to show the details obtained from `dictionary` on `tableViewCells` of `ViewControllerB`. I have already achieved this task through `Notifications` but I am not able to understand that how same task can be done through `delegates` and it is required to implement through `delegates`.

```
#####Code for Network Class

-(void)getResponse:(NSString *)url{

NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];

NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest: urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    //check if we encountered an error
    if(error != nil){
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }else{
        //get and check the HTTP status code
        NSInteger HTTPStatusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];
        if (HTTPStatusCode != 200) {
            NSLog(@"HTTP status code = %ld", (long)HTTPStatusCode);
        }

        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            if(data != nil){
                NSError *parseError = nil;
                NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];

                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ReloadNotification"
                                                                    object:self
                                                                  userInfo:responseDictionary];
                NSLog(@"The response is - %@",responseDictionary);


            }
        }];
    }
}];


[task resume];
}
```

`ViewControllerClass` having button:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(notifyReload:) name:@"ReloadNotification" object:nil];
}
```

Kindly explain with code how the task can be achieved through `delegates`? I am in my initial phase of development... after reading several tutorials then also couldn't understand `delegates`.

Comment: what you are trying to do neither requires `delegates` nor `notifications`. Why do you want to do it using `delegates`? Is it an assignment or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will help you

ViewControllerA.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class  ViewControllerA;
@protocol ViewControllerADelegate <NSObject>

- (void)viewControllerA:(ViewController *)viewControllerA showDictinaoryDataOnTableView:(NSDictionary *)dict;

@end

@interface ViewControllerA : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign)id<ViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

- (IBAction)doneButtonTapped:(id)sender;
@end
```

ViewControllerA.m

```
#import "ViewControllerA.h"
#import "ViewControllerB.h"
@interface ViewControllerA ()

@end

@implementation ViewControllerA



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


- (IBAction)actionGoNext:(id)sender;
{
   [self.delegate viewControllerA:self showDictinaoryDataOnTableView:dict];  //Here pass your dict
   ViewControllerB *vcB = [ViewController  alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerB" bundle:nil;
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:vcB animated:YES];
}
```

ViewControllerB.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewControllerB.h" 
@interface ViewControllerB : UIViewController <ViewControllerADelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tblDictData;
@end
```

ViewController.B

```
#import "ViewControllerB.h"

@interface ViewControllerB ()

@end

@implementation ViewControllerB

@synthesize tblDictData;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewControllerA:(ViewControllerA *)viewControllerA showDictinaoryDataOnTableView:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    yourdict = dict;    
    ... Must Do your stuff for showing data from dictionary to table view here 
    //Then reload the table view
    [tblDictData reloadData];    
}
```